# Android app crashes on startup in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, crash, android-logcat

I'm trying to make an android app, and when I try to test it in the emulator, the error pops up saying, **Unfortunately, komok has stopped** (komok is the name of my app) I have used Logcat to try and make some sense of it all, but since I am no good with Java development I can't seem to see what I need to fix, if someone could take a look at this and tell me what I am doing wrong, I would be very grateful.

Here is the Logcat:

```
07-06 09:35:05.204    4934-4934/p110.uk.helloworld E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: p110.uk.helloworld, PID: 4934
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{p110.uk.helloworld/p110.uk.helloworld.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2255)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:836)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:631)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:108)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
        at p110.uk.helloworld.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5720)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1102)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2208)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:143)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1258)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5070)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

If someone can tell me what the problem is and how I can fix it that would be great, I think the problem is this:

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{p110.uk.helloworld/p110.uk.helloworld.MyActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

But I still have no idea how to fix the problem, so if someone does, please help me, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.Your project needs to include Android.AppCompact.v7

depends what your using

Android Studio : File -> Project Structure -> Dependenices - > press the plus and Libaray
and select the App Compact

Eclipse - go to Build path - > Libraries -> Add External Jar and add the AppCompat Jar from SDK

hope it helps.

2.if your Activity extends ActionBarActivity change it FragmentActivity

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out now, one moment

Comment: This worked apart from it was Activity not FragmentActivity, however, thank you for telling me where to find the dependencies, this was very helpful.

Comment: FragmentActivity is in the Support Libaray is on Support Package V4

Comment: That's weird... both Activity and FragmentActivity gave errors, but only Actvity gave the option to import and solve errors...

Comment: which Error do u get? and what API are you using?

Comment: Weirdly it seems to be working now, FragmentActivity gave me the option to import the class, so I have, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

Either:

- Extend MyActivity to **Activity**, not ActionBarActivity (or other
  supporting class).
- Import the AppCompat.v7 to your project. You might need to download Supporting Libraries first.

Comment: I have done this and I am receiving the error (Cannot resolve symbol 'app') on this line of code:
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
How would I go about fixing this? remove it? change ActionBarActivity to activity?

Comment: Please update your question with code from MyActivity.java and the minSdk that you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, sorry to waste your time actually the error just decided it wasn't an error after a few minutes... now it's just a warning about an unused import statement, thank you for your answer, it was very helpful. Just one thing in case anyone views this in the future, maybe it would be worth adding how to add the Appcompact library (like in the other answer below) I've marked this as the answer